# Session variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Hey guys, Im doing a series of if statements based on a session variable that is set (which looks at a value in the DB and then decides whether to empty the session, or name it. However I'm having problems in that the session is always named, regardless of whether the record in the database is '0' or not. The query works fine when run in mysql. Here's the code:

session_start();

```
$_SESSION['MemberType'] = '';

mysql_select_db($database_choices, $choices);

$query = "Select lifemember from registrants where username = '" . $_SESSION[kt_login_user] . "'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row['lifemember'] == '1')
    {
        $_SESSION['MemberType'] = 'LifeMember';
    }
    else if($row['lifemember'] == '0')
    {
        $_SESSION['MemberType'] = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precheck: If you are getting any 'Headers already sent...' then you have some output already on the page which is preventing the setting of session.

Otherwise try debugging steps like:

1) Do an `echo $row['lifemember']` inside the while loop so that you know REAL value of what's been fetched from DB.

2) In else block, change it to `$_SESSION['MemberType'] = 'Hello';` Then see, whether Hello is printed or not?

Comment: Cool cheers, setting the session as something else seems to have worked. I guess something was stopping it being set back to null.